# calculate with select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want that if I choose 75'000 or 100'000 either the result in "one" (see pic 2) is 100 or 1000000. Can you help me do it? I would appreciate your help!

here is my code so far:

```html
<div class="container content-center" id="margin">
  <form name="formcalc">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">select</label>
      <select class="col-sm-10 form-control">
        <option>Default select</option>
        <option>75'000</option>
        <option>100'000</option>
      </select>
      <!-- <div class="col-sm-10">                   
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="txtnum1">
                </div> -->
    </div>
    <fieldset disabled>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">One</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n1" name="txtres" value="CHF " readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Two</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n2" name="txtres2" value="CHF " readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button" id="btn6" class="btn btn-danger" value="Berechnen" onClick="sumValues();showDiv();">
    <button type="button" style="display:none;" class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                ohne Gewähr
            </button>
  </form>
  <hr class="featurette-divider">
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: please include javascript or jquery required to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I don't have any js or jquery

Comment: Please add an attempt at fixing this problem yourself to avoid downvotes. Simply asking others to do your work for you is not respectful of the volunteers' time.

Comment: @joap Um, this is calling some js functions? `onClick="sumValues();showDiv();"` and this question is tagged with jquery and javascript?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I didn't ask that someone is doing my work. I just asking for help for HOW can I do it, how to tackle it, any approach for me. Please be respectful. Thank you

Comment: @joap sry this was my code for another project not for this

Comment: I don't understand "if I choose 75'000 or 100'000 either the result in "one" (see pic 2) is 100 or 1000000"....can you elaborate on that and try to be clearer?

Comment: If I choose from the select tag the number 75000 than in the output right to the "One" field should be 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="selectOne" class="col-sm-10 form-control" onchange="setOne()">
    <option>Default select</option>
    <option>75'000</option>
    <option>100'000</option>
  </select>

. . . . . 
. . . . .
. . . . . 

<script>
  function setOne()
  {
       const selectOne = document.getElementById("selectOne");
       if (selectOne.options[selectOne.selectedIndex].text == "75'000")
           document.getElementById("n1").value = "100";
       else if (selectOne.options[selectOne.selectedIndex].text == "100'000")
           document.getElementById("n1").value = "1000000";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: this helped me to. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The exact requirements are a little unclear, and it sounds like your a relative beginner in front end development. Given that, I will treat this a little bit more as a learning experience than an exact answer to your exact question, so here are some assumptions:

Based on the markup, it looks like this is Bootstrap, so I'm going to assume jQuery is available (if jQuery is not included, it's easy enough to Google search to find out how to do that).

Let's also assume you're just including a `<script></script>` tag before the closing `</body>` tag - inside these  tags is where your JavaScript code will go.

And finally, as I mentioned your exact requirements were a little unclear, but I know that generally you want a value in a textbox to be set when a value from a select dropdown is chosen. So let's assume that your exact requirement is: you have a dropdown and a textbox. In the dropdown (`<select>`), you can choose from 2 values: 75,000 and 100,000. If you choose `75,000`, the value of the textbox becomes 100, and if you choose `100,000`, the value of the textbox becomes 1000000.

Ok so here's the code. It involves what's called an event listener - the browser is listening for a user event like clicking something or (in your case) a select dropdown value being changed. You're going to write code to listen for and respond to that event. In jQuery the syntax is pretty clear and succinct in this way, using the `.on()` method.

Given this HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Default select</option>
    <option value="75,000">75,000</option>
    <option value="100,000">100,000</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="myTextbox">
```

Your JavaScript would look like this:

```
$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
    let textboxValue;

    switch(this.value) {
        case '75,000':
            textboxValue = '100';
            break;
        case '100,000':
            textboxValue = '1000000';
            break;
        default:
            textboxValue = '';
    }

    $('#myTextbox').val(textboxValue);
});
```

Here's a JS Fiddle of the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/j06sw8af/1/

This should be enough to get you on track for solving your exact problem.

Comment: Thank you so much @jbyrd! It helped a lot and thats what I was lookinf for except that the values of the textboxes should appear after clicking the submit button. But I will try to solve it. Thank you so much again

Comment: Then run the script on clicking the Berechnen button.

Comment: @joap - glad to help! If my answer was useful, perhaps consider an upvote ;)